# drop duplicates of one column based on duplicates of another column keeping the other column duplicates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

Keeping the duplicates of name column, I want to drop the duplicates of Count column except the unique values of name column

here is a example df

| Count | name |
| --- | --- |
| yes | jhon |
| yes | marry |
| yes | marry |
| yes | ishita |
| yes | ishita |
| yes | ishita |

The result I want as :

| Count | name |
| --- | --- |
| yes | jhon |
| yes | marry |
|  | marry |
| yes | ishita |
|  | ishita |
|  | ishita |

#pandas #python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is

- `groupby()` and `cumcount()` instances of **Name**
- 0th instance, keep **Count** otherwise set to **NaN**

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Count   name
yes jhon
yes marry
yes marry
yes ishita
yes ishita
yes ishita"""),sep="\t")

df.Count=np.where(df.groupby("name",as_index=False)["name"].cumcount()==0, df.Count, np.nan)
```

|  | Count | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | yes | jhon |
| 1 | yes | marry |
| 2 | nan | marry |
| 3 | yes | ishita |
| 4 | nan | ishita |
| 5 | nan | ishita |

Comment: Thankyou very much @Rob Raymond tried very hard for this,
can you explain why for loop is not working in this dataframe

Comment: you have groups of data,  any looping solution will have to do grouping and can fall foul of any coding bug.  effectively the loop is in `cumcount()` in this solution